# Preserve base URL when loading assets on proxied web page

Tags: html, node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to host a site (called `site1`) nested within an existing domain (`www.gateway.com`).

e.g. Instead of `www.site1.com/profile`, it would be `www.gateway.com/site1/profile`.

I have an NGINX reverse proxy that detects the `/site1/` path and proxies it to some upstream machines:

```
location ~/site1/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass http://upstreams/$1$is_args$args;

  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

The proxy itself is working fine - it redirects all the paths correctly. However, the site's assets (e.g. JS, CSS, etc.) do not preserve the base path (`www.gateway.com/site1`).

e.g. It is trying to load `www.gateway.com/normalize.css`, when the actual asset lives at `www.gateway.com/site1/normalize.css`.

For reference, the HTML for `site1` is sourcing assets like so:

```
<link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I've also tried removing the leading `/` in the href, but this results in the asset's path including the full route (less the last fragment) - also not what is desired.

Note that `site1` works fine when hosted at the root of a domain (e.g. `www.gateway.com/profile`).

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: For those with a similar issue, I found this thread to be quite helpful: https://serverfault.com/a/932636/361504

Answer (score 0):

You might already have a block that checks for static fields that is messing up your asset delivery. To me what you are doing seems fine, but you have other nginx asset code possibly either on the upstream or site1 messit up. Add a block that checks for static files. If you are only doing this for one or two sites, this is reasonable.

The code below should work until you get us more info on other asset code.

```
location ~/site1/(.*)$ {

          location ~* \.(?:js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|svg)$ {
            alias /location/of/site1; 
            expires 1M;
            access_log off;
            sendfile on;
            sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
          }

          location ~* {
            try_files $uri @nonStatic;
          }


}

location @nonStatic {  
  proxy_pass http://upstreams/$1$is_args$args;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. If the static assets live at `www.gateway.com/site1/normalize.css`, my understanding is that the alias should be `/site1`? Even with this, the assets are still attempting to load relative to the original host (`www.gateway.com/normalize.css`).

Comment: Alias would be a location on your computer. So something like /home/francis/gateway.com/site1/

I think what you have done is fine, but you may have some asset code blocks in nginx that are doing something else.

Make sure to also reload the nginx configs after changing the configs.

Comment: The assets don't live on the host that is performing the reverse proxy - they reside in the upstream hosts.

Comment: I haven't ever used your setup. Try logging, where you are passing upstream:
https://serverfault.com/questions/871305/how-do-you-log-proxy-pass-in-the-nginx-access-log